# What is the difference between "curd" and "yogurt"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, dialects, subcontinental-english

Most people use the words *curd* and *yogurt* interchangeably.

Both are made by fermenting milk.

Is there a difference between the two, or are they the same?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that most people use *curd* and *yoghurt* interchangeably?

Comment: [Curd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curd) vs [youghurt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youghurt). This seems general reference.

Comment: Curds are cheese, and yogurt is a pudding-style desert made from active cultures.  They are not the same, other than they are both dairy products.

Comment: I don't know if this is true for other parts of India, but in Goa I happened to buy what to my taste was youghurt but it was labelled as "curd". Perhaps Serious had a similar experience.

Comment: "Most people" means "me and my two friends".  "Few people" means "everyone else".

Comment: Living here in the US, the only "curd" I know is a nursery rhyme about "curds and whey" ... but that has to be explained to curious children constantly, since they have never heard these words elsewhere.

Comment: @GEdgar 'most people' in the context apparently means many of the many millions in the Indian region. I'd say travel, travel, travel, with family, esp., the little ones.

Comment: @All Next time I'll be careful using 'most people'  :)

Comment: I thought I read something on here last week about "_polishing a curd_..."

Comment: Argh..I closed this before fully comprehending. This just seems like an accepted dialect variation.

Comment: You may then please 'unclose' it.

Comment: @Kris: ...apparently but not obviously. As to your advice, I'm guessing you've traveled with 'little ones' to realize how easy it is and how much they pick up?

Comment: @Kris: "please 'unclose it'"? I don't think that's how it works. I've -voted- to unclose it, but that's all most anybody can do (except a moderator).

Comment: I would personally use "curd" as a word for "yogurt". The latter is way too foreign to be an English word, considering how common the food is globally. So not why use an English term for it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In India, curd is marketed as "yoghurt."

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curd

*Curd* and *Yoghurt* are indeed used interchangeably in many parts of (mostly urban) India and the region in general, though probably not in the UK, the US and some other parts of the world. (Thanks to @Peter Shor for the guidelines).

Comment: Is this an answer? This doesn't look like an answer. It looks like a comment.

Comment: This is an authentic answer from first-hand experience. :-)

Comment: OK. I'm telling you it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Matt We're not extending the  discussion any more.

Comment: This is an answer, it shouldn't be downvoted (although maybe it should be rewritten so it sounds like an answer). The answer is: they mean the same thing in India (or at least parts of India), but not in most of the world.

Comment: "In India, the word curd always means plain yogurt ..." [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curd]

Comment: Now I see why @FumbleFingers doesn’t quite consider subcontinentals native English speakers. :(

Comment: @tchrist How does **that** disqualify my answer? :-) I didn't tell them to speak so.

Comment: There are radical differences between AmE and BrE -- we don't unupvote each other here for that, do we?

Comment: I was teasing! I certainly haven’t downvoted you!!

Answer (score 16):

[This answer](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060821102556AACd5hz) seems to do a good job of explaining the difference. Yogurt and curd are similar in that bacteria are used to produce lactic acid to thicken the milk. They're different in that yogurt is made with pure culture for consistency.

Comment: +1 Quite a canonical answer. And a great reference. (Actually, the references cited in your reference).

Answer (score 15):

They are totally different things. I am a Turk and both products are highly consumed in Türkiye. We call *curd* *lor* in Turkish, and it is very similar to cheese:

[image: Turkish curd]

On the other hand, *yoghurt* is a different product.

[image: Turkish yoghurt]

Both are made of milk.

Comment: Just wanted to add that curds can be soft (as depicted above) or [hard](http://www.osceolacheese.com/catalog/images/mixedcheddar.jpg).

Comment: This post was accidentally closed. We each may have to vote to reopen it. Please do. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Now 1 more vote is needed...

Answer (score 14):

Coming to the rescue of all those confused Indians.
In India,  yoghurt is '***dahi***' . Most Indians are confused because in India,the commercial name of yoghurt is '***curd***' at most places. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogurt.

'***Meetha dahi***' is flavoured(sweetened) yoghurt.

Outside India, what is recognised as curd is the preprocessed form of '***paneer***',i.e., ***paneer*** after the excess water(or ***whey***,as the rest of the world recognises it)is drained out and before the ***paneer*** hardens. This is called curd outside India.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curd - curd

For all those non-Indians, '***paneer***' is a form of cottage cheese made in India.
For the a detailed difference between yoghurt and curd, follow the links provided.

Answer (score 8):

In American English,

> [yoghurt (or yogurt)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yogurt)

is a milk-based food that is cultured with yoghurt-specific bacteria, is a soft and smooth, ranging from jello-like to almost pourable consistency served in a tub, usually eaten at breakfast time. It is usually mixed or served with fruit. There are hundred's of commercially available varieties.

> [curd](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/curd)

all by itself is rare in AmE except in technical circumstances. For the food 'cottage cheese', where milk has formed into 'curds', small lumps of congealed milk solids, by chemical processes (not bacterial ones). Cottage cheese is often labeled 'large curd' or 'small curd' (depending on the size of the gobbets of coagulated milk).

One would never mistake 'yoghurt' for 'curd' because yoghurt creamy smooth and sweet/sour, and 'curd' is a technical descriptor for a congealed bit of milk solids an sounds weird as singular. 'Curds' are what you might describe cottage cheese, and are lumpy bits, tasting cheesy.

Comment: Nitpick: I believe the curds in cottage cheese are composed largely of protein (casein), not just fat.  Note, for instance, that they have a very different texture from butter (which is mainly fat).

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point. I edited and waffled.

Comment: There are two different kinds of protein - the slow acting casein in the curd and the fast acting in the whey (liquid) of cottage cheese.

Comment: @Mitch So what is called "poutine" (cheese curds and gravy on fries) in Canada is actually what we would call "cottage cheese and gravy" in the U.S.?

Comment: @squidlydeux I've only had poutine twice and what was the cheese thing in them was not cottage cheese (as I know it in the US). It may have been _similar_ to cottage cheese, but only possibly because I really did not understand how to process it (cognitively). I processed it just fine as food. That said, I still don't know what poutine is. Chile-cheese fries? Mozzarella balls and brown sauce? I still don't know? Words fail the experience.

Answer (score 6):

***Curd*** is a more generic word than ***yoghurt*** - and curd is not always made from milk.  For example, you can also get lemon curd and bean curd.  Curd can simply mean a liquid that has "*[curdled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curdling)*".  Yoghurt on the other hand is more specific in definition.

Answer (score 4):

The question starts with two statements:

> Most people use the words curd and yogurt interchangeably.
>
> Both are made by fermenting milk.

Neither of these are necessarily true. The first answer refers to a wikipedia article which states the same thing and has a reference link back to this page. Which means the statement has no real reference (just an echo).

But onto the question:

> Is there a difference between the two, or are they the same?

Yogurt/Yoghurt is indeed fermented with a specific pair of bacteria, but curd is not, rather it is coagulated/curdled milk. Many things can cause curdling (including adding citric acid) but yogurt fermentation is the action of very specific bacteria that transform lactose into lactase.

Answer (score 3):

In India *curd* and *yogurt* are the same: "curd" is called *plain yogurt* and if we add something to  it, like fruit, it becomes *fruit yogurt*.

Answer (score 1):

In India, curd is often used when it is prepared domestically.  When produced on a large scale and packed, it is termed *yoghurt*.

Answer (score 1):

Both Curd and Yoghurt are made from milk by fermentation. If it is plain it is curd and if more sugar added it is called yoghurt.